# Python Scripts on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, python-3.5

I am a new python user. I need to run scripts written by (remote) coworkers.

My first install of Python is 3.5.0.rc1.  It was installed on a Windows 10 machine using the python webinstaller.

On installation, I told the installer to add all Python components, and to add Python to the PATH.  I authorized python for all users.

I can load and access Python through the command line.  It will respond to basic instructions (`>>> 1+1   2`).

However, I do not get the expected response from some basic commands (eg, `>>>import os` followed by `>>>print os.getcwd()` results in a syntax error rather than in a print of the directory containing the python executable).

Further, I can not get python to execute scripts (eg. `>>>python test.py`).  This results in a syntax error, which seems to point to various places in the script file name.  I have tried a quick search of previous questions on StackOverfow, and can't seem to find discussion of what seems to be a failure on this basic of level.

Perhaps I have not loaded all the necessary python modules, or is it something else that I'm missing

Comment: that print syntax is python 2.*. in python 3.* that is illegal syntax, as print is a function, not a keyword

Comment: Thanks.  You are absolutely correct.  Old Guy error.

Answer (score 3):

> I can load and access Python through the command line. It will respond to basic instructions (`>>> 1+1   2`).

This means Python was, in principle, correctly installed. Congratulations!

> Further, I can not get python to execute scripts (eg. `>>>python test.py`)

The `>>>` indicate you're trying to run this from the python prompt. That's wrong. You need to run python.exe with the script file as argument from the windows prompt (`cmd`).

> `>>>print os.getcwd()` results in a syntax error

That's because you're using python3 and `print expression` is python2 syntax that is now incorrect. You will either need to do

```
print(os.getcwd())
```

or install python2.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Frankly, I was embarrassed to ask questions at this level, but I was stuck, and needed to move forward quickly.  Your reply got me over the first speedbump.  Now, the main event....

Comment: @OldGuy: you're welcome. You're question was clearly written, and contained all the info that was necessary, which makes it a bit special among beginners' questions, so this was fun to answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

in python3 print is replaced by `print()` you can use this

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12281845)

Comment: @andlrc: Actually, not only is it *an* answer; it is the correct answer.  The lack of parentheses is the reason for the error.